# Using a Perl script to compare two files

Tags: perl, awk

I am trying to write a Perl/AWK script to compare two files' output in this format shown below:

(As of now I can `diff` the two files using
`grep -Fxvf file1 file2 > file3` which is not sufficient.)

Note: file1 is a superset of file2.

file1:

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
```

file2:

```
bbbb
cccc
```

Expected output file:

```
aaaa  No
bbbb  yes
cccc  yes
dddd  No
```

Comment: Is `file2` guaranteed to be a subset of `file1`? If not, what is the expected output for lines that appear in `file2` but not in `file1`?

Comment: yes, file2 is guaranteed to be a subset of file1

Comment: Why don't you use `diff`?

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { a[$0]; next } { print $0, ($0 in a ? "yes" : "no") }' file2 file1
```

That is:

```
NR == FNR {                             # while processing the first file
  a[$0]                                 # (i.e., file2) just remember what you
  next                                  # saw, and don't do anything else
}
{                                       # afterwards:
  print $0, ($0 in a ? "yes" : "no")    # print the line followed by "yes" or
                                        # "no" depending on whether the line
                                        # was seen before in file2
}
```

Comment: Getting output like this:(it is almost close it seems, first char appending after each yes/no)
noa
 yes
 noc
 nod

Comment: I can't really see what your actual output is from the comment. Can you post it again with `\n` instead of newlines, so I can see where lines begin and end?

Comment: noa\n
 yes\n
 noc\n
 nod\n

Comment: Odd. If you replace `$(NF + 1) = ($0 in a ? "yes" : "no")` with `$0 = $0 OFS ($0 in a ? "yes" : "no")`, does that change things? By the way, what version of awk are you using?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your output with the original code and gawk or mawk, but I have hunches where other awks might be picky. Can you try the edited code?

Comment: this is perfect. actually the problem was with me only, I was trying with windows file. Sorry for bothering you. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

In perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open ( my $file_2,"<", "file2.txt" ) or die $!;
my %seen;
while ( my $line = <$file_2> ) {
   chomp ( $line ) ;
   $seen{$line}++;
}

close ( $file_2 );

open ( my $file_1, "<", "file1.txt" ) or die $!; 
while ( my $line1 = <$file_1> ) {
   chomp $line1;
   print $line1, " ", $seen{$line1} ? "yes" : "no", "\n";
}
close ( $file_1 );
```

Prints:

```
    aaaa no
    bbbb yes
    cccc yes
    dddd no
```

You may want to apply a regex to clear up whitespace, such as `$line =~ s/^\s+//g;` but I wasn't sure if the whitespace at start of line was formatting, padding or actually important, so I didn't touch it.

Comment: Did you test this ? I am getting output `no no`.

Comment: Minor typo. Amended.